# Check instances of 3 paired letters

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

Say i have an array `char myArrray[5] = {'T','T','T','T','T'}` And i want to check how many instances of 3 pairs of `T` i have.

I have a forloop below that checks for all 3 instances of T. There should be 3 instances, but for some reason its not even entering the if statement that checks it.

Maybe im just lost im really sleepy.

There are 3 isntances of TTT throughout the array. Thats what we have to get the number 3 in the counter but we arent getting it. `(T{T[T)T}T]`

full code here: http://ideone.com/AWyOkH

Any ideas?

```
     for(int k = 0; k < lineInputs; k++)
{
    int counter=0;
    cout << (k+1) << " ";

    for(int u=0; u<arrayElements; u++)
    {
        //cout << myArray[u];
        if(myArray[u] == 'T' && myArray[u+1] == 'T' && myArray[u+2] == 'T')
        {
            counter++;
            cout << counter << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Does the issue lay with `if(myArray[u] == 'T' && myArray[u+1] == 'T' && myArray[u+2] == 'T')` ?

Comment: what is arrayElements set to? can you post the whole code?

Comment: arrayElements is set to 5.

Comment: What is `lineInputs` set to? Does your function even enter the outer loop? Why does this outer loop even exist?

Comment: You need to post the code - give your expectations on what it should output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine.

```
   char myArray[5] = {'T','T','T','T','T'};
    int lineInputs=1;
    for(int k = 0; k < lineInputs; k++)
    {
      int counter=0;
      cout << (k+1) << " ";
      int arrayElements=5;
      for(int u=0; u<(arrayElements-2); u++)
      {
         //cout << myArray[u];
         if(myArray[u] == 'T' && myArray[u+1] == 'T' && myArray[u+2] == 'T')
         {
             counter++;
             cout << counter << " ";
         }
      }
    }
```

Output I get is:

```
1 1 2 3
```

Comment: The output should be more like 1 3

Comment: 3 Meaning 3 instances. But its not working for me and i have no idea why.

Comment: @soniccool, Why `1 3`? It's outputting the counter each time it gets incremented. How would it jump from 1 to 3? Or do you mean as not printing the counter, just the result?

Comment: Nevermind i confused myself but yea i will post my entire code it doesnt work for me for some rason.

Comment: There ya go hopefully itll help

Comment: Also let me know what sample input can be used and the expected sample output?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21814/discussion-between-srinivas-and-soniccool)

Comment: Same input we can use as 5 and TTTTT

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, although the code you posted should have:

```
for(int u=0; u<arrayElements-2; u++)
```

Instead of:

```
for(int u=0; u<arrayElements; u++)
```

The output will be 1 1 2 3 because you first print k+1, and then the counter each time you find three consecutive "T"'s. What you have programmed is correct!